# stop threads when exception happen

Tags: python, multithreading, exit, terminate

I have 10 threads, the problem is when something wrong happens raising the exception, `bye` will be printed 10 times.

I just want to print it once, then terminate all the threads. Is there any solution for the problem?

```
from threading import Thread
def printmsg(msg,threadNumber):
    while True:
        try:
            print 'this is your message %s -- Thread Number:%s'%(msg,threadNumber)
        except:
              exit('Bye')

for i in range(0,11):
    Thread(target=printmsg,args=('Hello Wrold',str(i))).start()
```

Comment: Is the syntax error in your example code on purpose to raise an exception?

Comment: Well, you have fixed it in a meantime.

Comment: Incidentally you're launching 11 threads, not 10. Check your interval logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a flag in the threads. n the main loop, you could `join()` all threads successively in order to wait until they are gone and then print a message if the flag is set.

The flag could even be the value of the exception...

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread, Lock

stop = False
lock = Lock()

def printmsg(msg, threadNumber):
    global stop
    while True:
        try:
            if threadNumber in [3, 5, 7, 9]: # Something wrong happens
                raise NotImplementedError

            lock.acquire()
            if stop:
                lock.release()
                break
            print 'This is your message %s -- Thread Number: %s' % (msg, threadNumber)
            lock.release()
        except NotImplementedError:
            lock.acquire()
            if not stop:
                stop = True
                print 'Bye'
            lock.release()
            break

for i in range(0,11):
    Thread(target=printmsg, args=('Hello World', i)).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to join all the child threads by the main thread. And do your job in main thread.

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-

from threading import Thread

def printmsg(msg,threadNumber):
    while True:
        try:
            print 'this is your message %s -- Thread Number:%s'%(msg,threadNumber)
            raise
        except:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    for i in range(0,11):
        threads.append(Thread(target=printmsg,args=('Hello Wrold',str(i))))
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
    exit('Bye')
```